# how Send specific part of the sheet as email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

this script  sends a pdf copy to my email when I type Send in cell L6 , this code send the whole sheet and I need to send as only A1:J22 , any Ideas ?

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange('L6').getValue();
  if (r == "Send") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ssID = ss.getId();
    var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
    var sheetName = ss.getName();

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var email = "EMAIL HERE";
    var subject = "Daily report ";
    var body = "Please find the attached Daily report";

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" 
    + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + 
      "&exportFormat=pdf";

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    var contents = result.getContent();

    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {
      attachments: [{
        fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", 
        content: contents, 
        mimeType: "application//pdf"
      }]
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the cells of `A1:J22` and want to create them to PDF data.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, create a temporal sheet and copy the values of the cells of `A1:J22` to it. Then, the temporal sheet is converted to PDF file. And, the temporal sheet is deleted.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange('L6').getValue();
  if (r == "Send") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ssID = ss.getId();

    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // Added
//    var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId(); // removed

    var sheetName = ss.getName();
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var email = "EMAIL HERE";
    var subject = "Daily report ";
    var body = "Please find the attached Daily report";

    var tempSheet = ss.insertSheet("tempSheet"); // Added
    sheet.getRange("A1:J22").copyTo(tempSheet.getRange(1, 1)); // Added
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
    var sheetgId = tempSheet.getSheetId(); // Added

    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" + "format=xlsx" +  "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token}});
    var contents = result.getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments: [{fileName: sheetName + ".pdf", content: contents, mimeType: "application//pdf"}]});

    ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet); // Added
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)
- [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: It worked perfectly ! out of box thinking , thank you Tanaike.

Comment: @Aboude zoua Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.